# Single page turning functionality on iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

If I want a single page turn animation, not book style with two pages show and not the sticky notes ripping off a a page can I use a built in animation like page curl or do I have to use [leaves](https://github.com/brow/leaves)?

(The reason I ask is with a Google search I've found plenty of conflicting information.)

Comment: please clarify your question I cannot read anything from it. Maybe a few more dots and sentences will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use leaves if that is what you are looking for. The reason being is that Apple's has custom transitions that are for private use only - see the following question: [List of pushViewController Transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471624/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-pushviewcontroller-transitions).

Page Curl also appears to be using private APIs. [This article](http://iosdevgoodies.joostschuur.com/ibook-style-page-curl-animations) recommends using leaves to get the Page Curl animation. Good luck!

Comment: page curl is available since iOS 4 (or was it 3.2?). anyway it's now "legal" to use // edit: UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl since 3.2

Comment: Oh nice!! Good to know. Thanks! Here is a [list](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of the current available Modal Transitions. Hopefully this helps discover which "built in" transitions are available.

Comment: Sorry, the link doesn't send you to the 'UIModalTransitionStyle' section which contains the list of available transitions. You will need to scroll there.